# Sidekiq, running out of threads - Rails leaving and not reaping connection_pool threads

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sidekiq

We have a production system running in the following config:

```
Ruby 2.5.1
Rails 5.2.2
Sidekiq 5.2.5
Sidekiq-cron 1.1.0
Redis 4.1.0
```

```
  adapter: postgresql
  pool: 10
  reaping_frequency: 10
  timeout: 5000
  username: ...
  password: ...
  host: ...
```

It has 3 queues (default/high/med priority), each with 4 threads. We recently added a new sidekiq cron job that runs every 30 mins in the high queue and after a couple of days the system just goes into gridlock and no more threads can be spawned for connection pools. We've traced it to the 'high' queue and this new job, last time it hung up this 'high' queue had 1900 threads, almost all of which look to be 'connection pool'. A `kill -9` on the process for the queue and our supervisor restarts it and all is great again for a 5-7 days and then its down again.

This new job creates a number of new lists in a remote DB, we have the local ActiveRecord model for the local records and a superclass RemoteList model. We use `RemoteModel.establish_connection...`. transaction open, write, write..., close transaction, close connection. We talk to a large number of remote DBs and so this model works well for us.

The new worker is repeatedly calling out to the list publisher which has been in use for 3+ years with no lockup issued. We can see one new connection pool process get added each time we write to the remote DB via the old list publisher.

I've tried:

1. Manually getting connection from the pool and returning, for both ActiveRecord itself and our super class, one, both, none.
2. Wrapping the block in `ActiveRecord::Base.connection_pool.with_connection`

Neither of the above has any impact and the thread count just continually grows with each file we split out until we reach deadlock and no more threads. Reaping just doesn't seem to be doing anything at all. The only thing different in this worker is that it calls out to `open3.capture3` to a 'C' programme to do some file splitting much faster than we can do in ruby but I can see that the spawned shell has closed and completed but still we get these 'connection pool' threads.

Anyone out there have any good ideas.

Thanks
Kate

List Publish

```
CoreDBListModel.semaphore.synchronize do
    begin

      .... setup removed....
      CoreDBListModel.establish_connection(@config['database'])

      CoreDBListModel.transaction do
        core = CoreDBListModel.where(:description => list.list_id).first
        core.pending = true
        core.name = list.name
        core.tags = category.name
        core.pcount = list.count
        core.active = list.deleted ? 2:0
        core.save

        ... make list insert data.....
        mass_insert = "INSERT INTO #{mapping['table']} (data_id, data, fulldata) VALUES #{inserts.join(", ")}"
        CoreDBListModel.connection.execute(mass_insert)

      # Mark as completed
        core.pending = false
        core.save

      end

    rescue => e
      @code = 500
      @message = "Failed - #{e.message}, #{e.backtrace[0]}"
      Rails.logger.error("CoreDBList() - Publishing failed - #{list.list_id}")
      Rails.logger.error("CoreDBList() - Publishing failed - #{e.message}")
      Rails.logger.error("CoreDBList() - Publishing failed - #{e.backtrace.first(10).join("\n")}")
    ensure
      begin
        # Close our DB connection
        CoreDBListModel.connection.close
      rescue
      end
    end
  end
```

Have added an answer below with more details but basically the issue looks to be with Rails somewhere between 5.1.6 and 5.2.1. If we roll back to 5.1.6 the problem goes away.

https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/36333

Comment: My only suggestion would that the begin, rescue end block where you're calling `CoreDBListModel.connection.close` could easily be masking some issue with the closing happening properly. I'd consider at minimum doing some logging there to see if there is an issue there or even just not wrapping it in the rescue (but, it's prod, maybe you don't want that)

Comment: We're having the same issue on rails 5.2.4 and ruby 2.6.1. Trying to both upgrade to rails 6.1 and will try to downgrade our applications to solve this nightmare. The same code on rails 4 worked flawlessly. We also tried puma, thin and unicorn, all of them had the same issue, so its a rails issue and not server. Nearly each user request generates a new thread that never dies. We also use a multi-tenant approach.

Answer (score 1):

First identify rate at which threads leak - does it happen per each task run or sporadically over time? If former - you're lucky and can try debugging by logging `ObjectSpace.each_object(Thread).count` (beware, it's a heavy function, may not be suitable for highload in production) in several points in your code to try to detect where threads leak.

Suspect is the `Open3.capture3` - it launches two threads for reading stdin/stdout of the process and one more for reading process exit status, if you do not use separate stderr in your C code - I'd suggest switching to `capture2` and seeing if threads leak around 1/3 times slower. I remember having issues with popen3 and child process not using stderr or some combination of opening/closing std streams or not reading stdin, cannot recall details now.

Comment: We removed the Open3.capture3 from the code as a test and it was still throwing out threads, would appear not to be related. Thanks for taking an interest.

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer but an update on the issue, one of our servers went down again this morning with 31000+ threads on one of the sidekiq tasks.

It looks like this is an issue with Rails ActiveRecord, we can successfully leave sleeping threads behind with some test code. It's the 'CoreDBListModel.connection.close' thats putting the connection pool to sleep and it's never reaped because of its state.

It looks like the issue for us started when we migrated from Rails 5.1.5 to 5.2.1, if we roll back to that version the issue goes away, the issue also seems to be present in Rails 6 as a similar issue also raised by someone else, slightly different name but same issue:

https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/36333